# does the returned value in the return statement in a web-service sends it to the front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web-services

as shown below in the code, i have a web-service. when the method `getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange` returns successful results, i send response to the front-end via `res.send(....)`
my question is, what is the purpose of the return statement in the method? i mean for sending a response to the front-end one can use `res.send`, but how can i receive `return 'OK'` in the front-end

**code**

```
app.post('/getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange/', async (req, res, next) => {
if (req == undefined) throw new Error('req is undefined, has value:' + req)
if (!req.body) throw new Error('req.body is undefined, has value:' + req.body)
if (!req.body.wktRepr) throw new Error('req.body.wktRepr is undefined or not exist. Please check the key/value of the json object sent from the front-end. req.body.wktRepr:' + req.body.wktRepr)
if (!req.body.epsgCode) throw new Error('req.body.epsgCode is undefined or not exist. Please check the key/value of the json object sent from the front-end. req.body.epsgCode:', + req.body.epsgCode)

const wktRepr = req.body.wktRepr
const epsgCode = req.body.epsgCode
console.info(infoTag, 'posted body to /getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange/ contains::' + 'wktRepr:', wktRepr)
console.info(infoTag, 'posted body to /getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange/ contains::' + 'epsgCode:', epsgCode)

const wktInEPSG32632 = transformWKT(epsgCode, sysResources.CONST_EPSG_32632, wktRepr)
getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange('2019-10-05','S2_GermanyGrid', wktInEPSG32632, credentials.RASDAMAN_LOGIN_USER_NAME, credentials.RASDAMAN_LOGIN_PASSWORD, (resutlCode, contents) => {
    console.info(infoTag, '/getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange/::resultCode', resutlCode)
    console.info(infoTag, '/getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange/::content', contents)
    res.send('WS-results: ' + JSON.stringify({contents: contents}));
})
.then(response=>console.info({msg:infoTag + 'WS /getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange/ succeeded.', response: response}))
.catch(e=>console.error({msg:new Error(errorTag + 'WS /getTIFFForSubsetAsNIRRange/ failed.'),error:e}))
return 'OK'
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening to port', port);
});
```

Comment: What is sent to the front-end is managed by `res.xxx` methods - the `return`ed value goes nowhere and does nothing - which is fortunate, since the `return "OK"` is executed before any of the `res.send` can

Comment: You simply can't. Specially through simple `POST`, `GET` requests, reason being, as soon as you call `res.send` the response buffer is flushed and the connection to the socket is closed. You may want to include the `OK` in the resonse itself, like so - 
`res.send('WS-results: ' + JSON.stringify({contents: contents, status: "OK" }));`
If you want a persistent connection where you can send data multiple times, you may want to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).